# I cant find the Plugin Project in my newly installed Eclipse? Help

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

File > New > Other , but its not there. =(. I only see General, CVS, Java, Tasks, XML and Examples.

Do I need to install anything else to get the Plugin Project so I can use the wizard?
Thanks, I was planning to write some sweet plugins but I am stuck.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the [right package of Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).

The **[RCP edition](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/heliosr)** should give you what you are looking for.
See the [RCP tutorial for illustration](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html).

You can also update your existing Helios Eclipse, by Installing "General Purpose Tools" -> "Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment" and "Eclipse RCP Plug-in Developer Resources" from the Helios update site.

[alt text http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/images/update10.gif](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/images/update10.gif)

After that, you should see the right menu in File-> New Project:

[alt text http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/images/firstrcp02.gif](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/images/firstrcp02.gif)

Comment: Nope, it is not working. This one **Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment 3.6.2.r362_v20110203-7b7mFL2FET3dhHalh1iNZtL** is installed in my Helios 3.6 version, but still I cant see the Plugin project in the eclipse menu